# Unable to compile kotlin project with maven, unresolved reference for local dependency

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am working on a project in IntelliJ, there is a main project (called "TBDCore") that also acts as an API / Library for my other project, and a project that I added (called "WorldFund") which depends on the main project. Both projects use maven to manage dependencies, and both are built using `mvn clean kotlin:compile install`. The main project builds fine, however the project that depends on it throws the error "Unresolved reference: tbdcore" anytime I try and compile it.

IntelliJ shows no errors with importing anything from the TBDCore project, the unresolved references only appear during compilation.

I've googled and googled and found no working solutions, however i'll go over what I tested:

- Verified that TBDCore is in the .m2 repository, have also deleted and reinstalled it - same error
- IntelliJ Invalidating Caches / Restarting - same error
- Using standard maven `compile` command - same error
- Using `mvn clean kotlin:compile install` from the terminal instead of through IntelliJ - same error

One thing that seems to set my issue apart from other user's issues is that my projects are both entirely in kotlin, no java classes mixed in

TBDCore / library pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dev.mrshawn</groupId>
    <artifactId>TBDCore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TBDCore</name>

    <description>Core for TBD server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>co.aikar.commands</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.acf</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>de.leonhard</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.storage</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenCentral</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>aikar</id>
            <url>https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.simplix-softworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>SimplixStorage</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.aikar</groupId>
            <artifactId>acf-paper</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

WorldFund / project that won't compile pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dev.mrshawn</groupId>
    <artifactId>WorldFund</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WorldFund</name>

    <description>Fund various world events in-game</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.mrshawn</groupId>
            <artifactId>TBDCore</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The full error: https://pastebin.com/c5ze86ki (Using pastebin because the error puts me 20k characters over the limit)

Comment: If this is a multi-module project there must be an [aggregator project](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) containing `<modules>`. Why "_both are built using `mvn clean kotlin:compile install`_"? If you build just the aggregator the Maven Reactor takes care of building all (sub-)modules in one go.

Comment: BTW, you could also use [inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) (DRY) for the declarations that are the same in each of the (sub-)modules. `<scope>compile` is the default, you don't have to declare it explicitely. You don't have to declare default goal-to-phase bindings in `<plugins>`.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I guess in my case it could be looked at more as just a way of organizing things then. I'm sure I could setup something to build all the submodules, however the problem still remains of the sub-module being unable to compile

Comment: Then please don't call it _multi-module_ or _(sub-)module_ since that has this special meaning in Maven.

Comment: My apologies, i'll edit the post to remove this

Comment: What if you remove `<scope>provided` from the dependency `TBDCore` in `WorldFund`?

Comment: That still gives the same error

Comment: Please add all the lines of the build output to your Q that refer to the error.

Comment: Added to the bottom

Comment: I don't know if that could be the cause but you don't have `<build><sourceDirectory>...<testSourceDirectory>...` in your POMs as mentioned in [Compile Kotlin-only source code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#compile-kotlin-only-source-code). I guess your `import` statements in `FundCommand.kt` are OK, aren't they?

Comment: Even with the `<testSourceDirectory>` it still errors, the import statements don't show errors and everything looks fine when im editing the classes, it's only when I compile that I get the unresolved reference